# Capture network traffic programmatically (no root)

Tags: android, network-programming, android-networking, packet-sniffers

I'm trying to find resources or library which could permit me to capture the traffic of all the network packets of a device programmatically either it be from wifi or mobile network. I believe there no need to be root to be in this promiscuous mode as [shark for root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark&hl=fr) would request because there is [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=fr) on the play store which can capture all network traffic (even decrypt SSL with MITM) without needing to be root. I simply cannot figure out how to do the same.

My question is: How did this app achieve this capture? What API did they use?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: People shouldn't just down vote without having any clue about the topic and providing no reason for their downvote.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The de-facto appraoch to packet sniffing in Android without root is loop-back [VPNService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html). Creating a VPNService app and activating it, will force all traffic in the device to go through your newly created virtual interface which is managed by a userspace application, where you will be receiving IP Packets by reading from the virtual interface.

You can check a simple code sample for it from Google [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/ToyVpnService.java)

You can check a full working example project [here](https://github.com/hexene/LocalVPN)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: There are loads of FOSS solutions on GitHub that uses this local VPN solution. Also many other Network, VPN and WiFi tools allow you to save/get packets in `pcap` format.

Comment: Most of these capture apps break the internet connections so It's hard to even debug the apps, ironically.