# Monitoring DHCP info with Android Applicaition without Root

Tags: java, android, dhcp, packet-sniffers

The DHCP Request is a broadcast UDP packet，Theoretically I could snnifering it with the Port 67(which dest port of DHCP Request)
For example, I could snnifering other device DHCP Request info in LAN under mac os Wireshark

But With Android Application When I run

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket("67");
```

I get Exception with  **java.net.bindexception bind failed access (permission denied)**  Which since I may not bind port under 1024

So Is there any other API or Method I could sniffering without root privilage?

**PS: [Fing Mobile SDK](https://www.fing.com/news/device-intelligence-the-game-changing-sdk-api) claim it does contains [DHCP monitoring](https://www.fing.com/images/uploads/general/Fing_Mobile_SDK_Developers_Guide_3.2.pdf) so it may have someway doing this**

**PSPS: It seems Fing implement DHCP sniifer by it's Fingbox**

Comment: Deleted old comment. You probably have a chance with a VPNService.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38679210/6459327

Comment: @Enak Thx for the Ref, Seems too heavy for me